# Formato de fecha al importar de Excel

Tags: python, pandas, formato

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con `DataFrames` en Pandas. En mi caso, el formato original en la hoja Excel es "dd-mm-YY". Al importar a un DataFrame con pandas, mediante la sentencia

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, parse_dates=['Fecha'], dayfirst = True)
```

el formato que me presenta es "YY-mm-dd" ("`Fecha`" es el nombre de la columna en la que tengo introducidas fechas).

No solo no mantiene el formato original, si no que lo modifica. ¿Qué opciones tengo para cambiar ese formato y volver al original, actuando sobre el DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo aclarar que esto es un problema de visualización y que no afecta en absoluto a los cálculos que se puedan aplicar en la columna. en realidad la fecha tiene formato datetime64 de NumPy que la guarda en nanosegundos, es a la hora de imprimir los datos cuando se trasforman en algo humanamente legible.

En teoría existe una forma de hacer lo que quieres con [`pandas.set_options`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option) usando la opción `display.date_dayfirst`. Digo en teoría porque al menos **a día de hoy con `pandas 0.20.3` no parece estar correctamente implementada** y no parece funcionar

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> pd.set_option('display.date_dayfirst', True)
>>> pd.set_option('display.date_yearfirst', False)
>>> df = pd.read_excel('datos.xlsx', parse_dates=['Fecha'], dayfirst = True ) 

>>> pd.get_option('date_dayfirst')
True
>>> df
       Fecha
0 2017-01-10
1 2017-05-12
2 2016-03-04
3 2016-10-08
```

Esto seria lo optimo si funcionara... La otra opción es pasar la fecha a una cadena usando [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) para formatearla a nuestro antojo. el problema es que la columna ahora contendrá datos de tipo `object` que son strings de Python. El problema es que no podemos operar con ellos como fechas (filtrar, agregar días, etc)

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.read_excel('datos.xlsx', parse_dates=['Fecha'], dayfirst = True ) 
>>> df['Fecha2'] = df['Fecha'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
>>> df

       Fecha      Fecha2
0 2017-01-10  10-01-2017
1 2017-05-12  12-05-2017
2 2016-03-04  04-03-2016
3 2016-10-08  08-10-2016

>>> df.dtypes
Fecha     datetime64[ns]
Fecha2            object
dtype: object
```

En este caso se crea una nueva columna para ver la diferencia, también se puede sustituir directamente la columna `Fecha`. El problema, repito, es que la columna ya no es de tipo `Datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, con mi versión de Pandas, incluida en Anaconda2, tampoco funciona. No obstante he aprendido de Su respuesta, conceptos fundamentales:

a).- El formato "fecha" en el Dataframe creado con pandas es  **datetime64** **de **NumPy**** que la guarda en nanosegundos. (Investigaré más en Numpy acerca de este formato y sus posibilidades)

b).- Existe la opción de pasar la fecha a una cadena usando `strftime`, pero ya no podría hacer operaciones con las fechas.

c).- En caso de que a algún usuario no le importara tener las fechas como strings, existe la opción de importarlas con **openpyxl**.

```
import openpyxl

wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('fichero.xlsx')
```

El formato de salida del DataFrame es

```
<class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet
```

y las fechas son strings.